# Adding Hostname as a Custom Varnish Header

Tags: configuration, varnish

I've several varnish cache servers (v2.1), and I'm looking to add the hostname in the headers in the response from varnish -- so I know which server is (or not) serving cached pages. Upon googling, [I found this snippet](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/varnish/misc/14277), but it gives errors:

```
sub vcl_deliver {
  if (obj.hits > 0) {
    set resp.http.X-MH-Cache ="HIT " obj.hits " "*
    server.hostname* " " resp.http.Age;
  } else {
    set resp.http.X-MH-Cache ="MISS " *server.hostname* ""
  }
}
```

I am not tied to this snippet per se. Ideally, I would like to set hostname in the event of a miss or a hit.

I am fairly new to vcl files, so any guidance and assistance would be much appreciated. Many thanks!

KM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled upon this by chance (isn't it always that way?): https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleHitMissHeader -- exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This is not a correct answer (linking to documentation)

Answer (score 0):

More likely the error was due to the star signs, and missing plus signs when building up the "**X-MH-Cache** response header:

```
Unknown token '*' when looking for STRING
```

The working vcl code snippet looks like this:

```
vcl 4.1;
import std;
sub vcl_deliver {
  if (obj.hits > 0) {
    set resp.http.X-MH-Cache = "HIT: " + obj.hits + " *" + server.hostname + "* Age: " + resp.http.Age;
  } else {
    set resp.http.X-MH-Cache = "MISS *" + server.hostname + "*";
  }
}
```

A snapshot (January 2nd, 2012) to the URL from of the answer (January 27th, 2012) can be found on the Internet Archive site here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20120309095329/https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleHitMissHeader